# Node OpenCV Operations on Arrays

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-processing

I am developing an app with NodeJS and OpenCV. I am using the node-opencv bindings done by Peter Braden ( github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv )

The problem I have is that I need to use the math array operations that OpenCV has, in the NodeJS app. I mean, this, http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

The idea is to implement in Node this algorithms to make ilumination normalization in images https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/blob/master/misc/tan_triggs.cpp

I can't find how to access pow, mean, substract, etc functions from the OpenCV library. 
The Math native JS object is not useful for this purpose since I need to make all the operations in an OpenCV Matrix.

Dows anyone know where are the bindings to these functions in node-opencv ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I could find several bindings, but looks like Matrix.pow() has not been implemented in the bindings.